Multiple domains on nginx on centos 9
I have 2 domains I would like to run using nginx.
First domain is hosted on wordpress on /var/www/html, so easy to attach the root
Second domain is openproject running on docker (8080:80).
I am using certbot to manage the routes.
The wordpress domain is working well on port 80, but I wonder how I can add the new domain on the same script using port 8080.
My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf code is attached.
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events 
{
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        server_name  _;
        root         /var/www/html/wordpress;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

}
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/.../fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/.../privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

    //Domain 1 which is accessible
    server {
    if ($host = project1.domain.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

    //Tried to add this block for domain 2 but its not working with error 502 Bad gateway
    server {
    if ($host = project2.domain.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen       8080;
        listen       [::]:8080;
        server_name  _;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

